# java nio reading lines from a file

Tags: java, performance, io, nio

How do i implement a function in java nio say nextLineNio() which reads next line from FileChannel incrementally as the file could be huge, my initial idea was to read into a ByteBuffer of size greater then maximum length of a line which could exist and read() from the FileChannel if required, but the problem which i see is how do i un-read the last sequence of bytes which do not end in a newline. Also how do i ensure that the nextLineNio() function doesn't fails as the nio api is asynchronous. Any help or already existing implementations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As @EJP points out, it is quite likely that you will get more than enough performance using BufferedReader.readLine()  Unless you know this is not suitable, this is what I would suggest you keep things simple.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-slow-can-you-readwrite-files-in.html

---

I would memory map the whole file and search for newlines to get a line at a time. This avoid the need to worry about buffer sizes or multiple reads (or the problem of reading too much)

NIO is **synchronous** by default, file IO is only synchronous (until Java 7). To make Sockets asynchronous you have to call a special setter.

Comment: I wouldn't. I would use a BufferedReader. I wouldn't use mapped NIO for anything except a large single file that was going to be open for the lifetime of the program, e.g. a self-implemented database.

Comment: @EJP, Excellent point.  I should have asked whether you need NIO in the first place.